# Mocking IElasticClient in unit tests

Tags: c#, nunit, moq

I'm trying to unit test how my class responds to a NEST 1.7 `IElasticClient`'s return values, using NUnit 2.6.4 and Moq 4.2. I feel mocking the `Get` function requires *very* "heavy" `It.IsAny` calls, and am *mainly* looking for *feedback on how to mock `IElasticClient` in a way that my tests remain readable*.

My code is mostly 100% actual code, with the exception of:

- The Repository and Person classes are simplified (I'm mainly looking for feedback on the Test method);
- I'm expecting a generic `Exception` but in reality I've got a custom exception class there;

Here's the code:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get; set; }
}

public class PeopleRepository
{
    private IElasticClient client;

    public PeopleRepository(IElasticClient Client)
    {
        this.client = Client;
    }

    public Person Get(string id)
    {
        var getResponse = client.Get<Person>(p => p.Id(id));

        if (getResponse.Source == null)
        {
            throw new Exception("Person was not found for id: " + id);
        }

        return getResponse.Source;
    }
}

[TestFixture]
public class PeopleRepositoryTests
{
    [Test]
    public void RetrieveProduct_WhenDocNotFoundInElastic_ThrowsException()
    {
        var clientMock = new Mock<IElasticClient>();
        var getRetvalMock = new Mock<IGetResponse<Person>>();

        getRetvalMock
            .Setup(r => r.Source)
            .Returns((Person)null);

        clientMock
            .Setup(c => c.Get<Person>(It.IsAny<Func<GetDescriptor<Person>, GetDescriptor<Person>>>()))
            .Returns(getRetvalMock.Object);

        var repo = new PeopleRepository(clientMock.Object);

        Assert.Throws<Exception>(() => repo.Get("invalid-id"));
    }
}
```

Any way I can improve the way I'm mocking `IElasticClient`?

Comment: Just a technical observation, those are stubs, not mocks.

Comment: Since you create objects with Moq using the `Mock<T>()` function I tend to call all those objects a "mock", regardless of whether it's technically a fake, stub, double, mock, or dummy. Duly noted though :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's fine. Yes, in an ideal world, we'd verify that the `id` we passed into the `PeopleRepository.Get()` method is the same one that's getting passed to the `client.Get()` method, but that's also getting down into testing the internal implementation of the method. What you really care about here is that when the `Person` isn't found, a specific exception is thrown, so in this particular case it's fine.

Remember, we want to tests for specific results, not the internal implementation.

I'm going to quote [Jon Skeet's comment to a related SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12778579/func-nunit-equality-comparison#comment17273022_12778671).

> I would test that the usage of those functions do the right thing, rather than testing that the exact same function is used. – Jon Skeet Oct 8 '12 at 9:33